# SQL Server Export Wizard Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm hoping someone can help me.  I have a big query, like 2 million records.  It has some exotic characters, and I think some of the values have commas which is making it difficult to export the query results to a flat file and then import them into another table in a different server and database.

I've been trying to use the export wizard so I can change the column delimiter to tab, but I'm getting the errors below I think because of the exotic characters and merged values.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Errors:

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "ACCOUNT_NM" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc02020a0: Data Flow Task 1: Cannot copy or convert flat file data for column "ACCOUNT_NM".
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - TestExport_txt" (172) failed with error code 0xC02020A0 while processing input "Flat File Destination Input" (173). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - Query" (1) returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 0):

The truncation error essentially means there is something wrong with your metadata either in your source or destination.  You can set the column to "ignore truncation error" and test to see if your data is still accurate...if not then you will need to check your metadata and make the relevant change.

Answer (score 0):

In Import Export wizard, while configuring Destination, try using `Code Page` to `UTF-8`, Text qualifier as  `"` and choose column delimiter as of your choice. Also try with and without checking `Unicode` option. While editing  mappings, select data type and size accordingly source. Most of time `DT_TEXT` or `DT_NTEXT` will work for all columns.

You can this resource helpful for SSIS data type mappings - [SSIS Data Type Mapping](http://milambda.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/sql-server-integration-services-data.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me on this.  I tried importing with UTF-8, text quilifier ", and setting a few of the problem fields to DT_TEXT.  When I tried selecting Unicode it couldn't find the column delimiters, so I didn't do that.  It gave me the error messages:Error 0xc0202055: Data Flow Task 1: The column delimiter for column "PARENT_ACCOUNT_NM" was not found.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "D:\Documents\James Project\Main Table\outer_query_new.csv" on data row 65327.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - outer_query_new_csv" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)